# .NET 6 Custom model binding - fall back to default binding?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, model-binding, .net-6.0

I am trying to change the way one specific property of my Specification models are bound in .NET 6. I have a bunch of Specification classes that inherit from `SpecificationBase<>`. There is an `int[]? Ids { get; set; }` property that is part of the base class. I created a custom binder to take a CSV string of numbers and convert them to an int[]? array. (**Note:** I am aware the arrays can be passed to controller actions in the form `?Ids=1&Ids3=&Ids=5` which will bind correctly to arrays).

In older examples I've seen on the web, custom model binders inherited from `DefaultModelBinder`. We could then use `base.BindModel` or `base.BindProperty`. I cannot find anything similar for .Net 6. There is a `ComplexObjectModelBinder` but it is sealed.

Everything below works okay as long as the Specification properties are simple types. The `TypeDescriptor` conversion seems to work well for those. I'm worried about when there are complex types. Is there a way to fall back to default binding for everything other than my `Ids` property?

```
public class SpecificationModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(bindingContext);

        // If not a specification, skip
        if (bindingContext.ModelType.BaseType?.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof(SpecificationBase<>))
            return Task.CompletedTask;

        // Type of specification
        var type = bindingContext.ModelType;

        // Create default instance of the specification
        var model = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

        // We are passing the specification parameters via the querystring, so loop over the querystring keys to set specification properties
        foreach (var name in bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Query.Keys)
        {
            // Check to make sure there is a matching property. If not continue.
            var property = type.GetProperty(name);
            if (property is null)
                continue;

            if (property.Name == "Ids")
            {
                // Custom binding to convert int csv string into int[] array
                string? idsString = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("Ids").FirstValue;
                int[]? ids = null;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(idsString))
                    ids = idsString.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Where(x => int.TryParse(x, out _)).Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
                property.SetValue(model, ids);
            }
            else
            {
                // Is there a standard way to bind all of the other properties? This will only handle simple types
                var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(property.Name).FirstValue;
                var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(property.PropertyType);
                var convertedValue = converter.ConvertFrom(value!);
                property.SetValue(model, convertedValue);
            }
        }

        // Set the result to our populated model
        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it worth creating special binder for the property and mark all `Ids` properties with it? Also you can try to create [`IModelBinderProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#implementing-a-modelbinderprovider) which will check property type and name and return your custom binder (which should handle only the property).

Comment: Guru, the specifications are in a separate assembly with no dependencies on `Microsoft.AspNetCore`, so I'm not sure I can make your first suggestion work. With regards to the 2nd suggestion, I only want the custom handling to occur for the `Ids` property of specifications that are derived from `SpecificationBase<>` . I am trying to explicitly opt in to the binder by doing something like `public async Task<IActionResult> List([ModelBinder(typeof(SpecificationModelBinder))] CountrySpecification specification)` in my controllers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really just looking to have a custom model binder for just one property.

You can actually set the Binder on the property level specifically. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#modelbinder-attribute

Going from what I can from your example:

```
class CountrySpecification : SpecificationBase<>
{
    //Country specific properties handled by the default Binders
}
```

```
class SpecificationBase<> 
{
    [ModelBinder(typeof(SpecificationModelBinder))]
    int[]? Ids { get; set; }
    //Extra properties handled by the default Binders
}
```

Another added benefit is now your custom Binder handle your one property as well.